# if i use qr adapters will it make my 135mm wheel to a 142mm or will it stay the same

Tags: mountain-bike

I have a 142"mm hub now but it is worn out and i need a new one. I found a 135"mm hub but it is a thru axle but i need a qr. can i use adapters and will they make it wider and closer to my original 142"mm wheel?

Comment: The correct width of the hub is generally a function of the number of cogs on the rear freewheel/freehub.

Comment: The width of the hub is also function of axle type. Usually it's 135mm for MTB QR and 142mm or more for through axle. Are you sure you got these right?

Comment: Please identify the hub model, the answer varies.